# Spring hibernate mvc - loop in frontend

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jsp, loops

I created a web application based on spring 4.3 and hibernate 5.2,

when it comes to querying for data and display data in frontend(jsp), i get stuck...

controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    List<Article> articles = articleDao.list();

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test");

    model.addObject("articles", articles);

    return model;

}
```

test.jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="article" items="${articles}">
    ${article.name} <br/>
</c:forEach>
```

i have four records in database and this is displayed in frontend:

```
<c:foreach items="[com.example.app.model.Article@41d04f4b, com.example.app.model.Article@1b56d335, com.example.app.model.Article@30f1547d, com.example.app.model.Article@5e30ea41]" var="article">
<br>
</c:foreach>
```

When i log hibernate sql statement using log4j2, i get this output:

```
select
    article0_.id as id1_0_,
    article0_.name as name2_0_,
from
    s_articles article0_
```

Anybody can help with this issue?
For now i just want to query for data from my database(articles) and display them on frontend (.jsp-pages).

Thanks and Greetings!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

to your file ?

I think You will have to add the JSTL for using c:forEach, doing this should fix your issue.